# R: List of Matrices with every i-th column equal to zero

Tags: r, matrix

Assume we have the following matrix given:

```
mat <- matrix(1:20,4,5)
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
```

I want to transform this matrix into a list with length equal the number of columns, such that every i-th column is full with zeros.

I.e. for this special case I want the following:

```
list(matlist)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    5    9   13   17
[2,]    0    6   10   14   18
[3,]    0    7   11   15   19
[4,]    0    8   12   16   20

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    9   13   17
[2,]    2    0   10   14   18
[3,]    3    0   11   15   19
[4,]    4    0   12   16   20

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    0   13   17
[2,]    2    6    0   14   18
[3,]    3    7    0   15   19
[4,]    4    8    0   16   20

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9    0   17
[2,]    2    6   10    0   18
[3,]    3    7   11    0   19
[4,]    4    8   12    0   20

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13    0
[2,]    2    6   10   14    0
[3,]    3    7   11   15    0
[4,]    4    8   12   16    0
```

Any ideas how I could do this in general for large matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)), function(j) {mat[,j] = 0; mat})

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    5    9   13   17
[2,]    0    6   10   14   18
[3,]    0    7   11   15   19
[4,]    0    8   12   16   20

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    9   13   17
[2,]    2    0   10   14   18
[3,]    3    0   11   15   19
[4,]    4    0   12   16   20

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    0   13   17
[2,]    2    6    0   14   18
[3,]    3    7    0   15   19
[4,]    4    8    0   16   20

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9    0   17
[2,]    2    6   10    0   18
[3,]    3    7   11    0   19
[4,]    4    8   12    0   20

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13    0
[2,]    2    6   10   14    0
[3,]    3    7   11   15    0
[4,]    4    8   12   16    0
```